# Hyper-v: give VM internet access in case of two scope IPs?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, network-adapter, windows-server-2012-r2, internet-sharing

**(I)-** I have a VPS with VT CPU declared. (Windows server 2012 r2 Datacenter)

**(II)-** So, installed a nested VM in Hyper-v Manager. (Windows 10 Enterprise)

**(III)-** Created an External Switch:↓
[image]

**(IV)-**  With this settings in Host (Windows server 2012)
[image]

[image]

**(V)-** VM Settings: (Win10-1)↓
[image]

[image]

**(VI)-** But no internet access! In case of Default gateway has pinged and folder sharing is true.
[image]

What is the problem, internet access of my VM (Win10-1)?

Any helps are appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

The VM has an IP address of `10.10.1.1` and its gateway is `54.37.198.219`.

While the address `54.37.198.219` does belong to the host, it is not on the
same network segment as the VM, so is unreachable from the VM.
The VM can only use for the gateway IP addresses from the network of
`10.10.1.x`.

The host has two IP addresses: `54.37.198.219` and `10.10.1.100`.

You need to use as the gateway for the VM the IP address that is on the same
network segment, which in your case is `10.10.1.100`.

(Note: In the usual case the host should be `10.10.1.1` and the VM some other
`10.10.1.x`, so it seems that IP assignments here are somewhat reversed.)

Comment: The answer does not true.

My host in situation with above IP assigned with ISP and that is my principle and I can not change. 
I can only change in VM IP address setting. Please revert your answer.

Comment: That's what I mean : Set the gateway *of the VM* to `10.10.1.100`.

Comment: The VM cannot access directly the internet, it can only access the internet by going through the host. It's the host that has the direct contact to the internet. The VM needs to use the host as the gateway and that's why the host is available on its subnet. The host address is `10.10.1.100` on that subnet, and that's the gateway for every computer on the subnet of `10.10.1.x` including the VM.